# Deciding on SQL Server 2008 License, Processor vs CALS

Tags: sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

The company I am at has decided to bring in our outsourced website and database.  We are trying to figure out what the best pricing option would be.  Our IT team is very small (3 people), but the SQL Server we purchase would be our back end to the IIS site.  The Database itself is only about 50 tables so I would hate to spend thousands for a processor license, but as i understand the alternate route is i would need a CAL for every single visitor to our site?  Are there any better options i am missing?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Do you absolutely need MSSQL Server? would one of the open-source SQL servers not do?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft actually requires a per-processor license for any SQL Servers that are used as the backend of a website for this very reason.  You could check to see if either the Express or Workgroup Editions would meet your needs, but if you need the full Reporting Services and SSIS functionality, you'll probably have to go with Standard Edition.

Comment: This has been my understanding for many years.

Comment: If the web site is not for *line of business* applications (eg. is a company presentation site) then a Web Edition SQL Server can be used, which is way cheaper. http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/web.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SPLA. You need SPLA pretty much - under which you RENT the server monthly (which interesting enough everyone else here seems to not even know). Prices are a lot lower. Depending which SQL Server you need you can start free (Express, 10gb) and go through web, standard up to enterprise.

Licensing under SPLA for hosting is ONLY per processor.

Same btw. , for your web server / OS.... purchased licenses are not viable for stuff like that - neither legally nor financially.

Comment: unless it was very recently changed, SPLA also had a per user option, not just a per proc license. Typically you start up as per user then go to per proc